# Python2.6 - Error loading data into Influx database

Tags: python, database, insert

I'm using python2.6 to load records into Influx database. This is my influx point:

```
influx_point = {
  "measurement": "%s"%measurement,
  "tags": {
        "domain": "%s"%domain,
        "host": "%s.%s"%(host,domain),
        "tag1": "",
        "tag2": ""
        },
  "time": timestamp,
  "fields": {
        "value": value
        }
  }
```

Tyep of *measurement* is string. And this is the error it returns:

```
errore:  400: {"error":"field type conflict: input field \"value\" on measurement \"hsm.recall.succeeded\" is type float, already exists as type integer dropped=206"}
```

Could someone explain me why?